# How to use authenticated repo in bazel for thirdparty dependant artifacts

Tags: authentication, bazel

My code depends on some thirdparty artifacts, that are put in some authenticated repo. 
WORKSPACE file is like this

```
http_archive(
  name = "glog_archive",
  build_file = "@//:third_party/BUILD.glog",
  sha256 = "SOME SHA ID",
  url = "https://artifactory/thirdparty/glog.<version>.tar.gz",
)
```

But repo https://artifactory/thirdparty/ is authenticated.

How can I put user/password or API key so that download of thirdparty archives works well?

Went through this doc https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/repo/http.html#http_archive-auth_patterns

But couldnot get it correctly.

If there any example I can get?

Thanks

-Gaurav

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how (can) are you trying to authenticate to your artifactory instance. If you rely on HTTP basic authentication scheme either using a username and paswword (or username and API key; or username and access token), you need to add those to corresponding machine entry in [`.netrc`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/netrc) file, e.g.:

```
machine your.artifactory.host
        login YOUR_ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME
        password YOUR_PASSWORD_OR_KEY_OR_TOKEN
```

You can either add path to the `netrc` file in eponymous attribute of the `http_*` repository rules. Or bazel will look for it as `${HOME}/.netrc` for non Windows system and very recently (in master, but not yet in 3.0.0 release) as `%USERPROFILE%/.netrc`.

Using API alone (with `X-JFrog-Art-Api`) is not supported by `http_*` rules.

You only needs to use `auth_patterns` if you were not using basic authentication scheme. I.e. you wanted to use the Artifactory access token as a bearer token. In which case you would add:

```
auth_patterns = {
    "your.artifactory.host": "Bearer <password>"
}
```

You then add the token into your `netrc` (see above if it needs to be explicitly added to the rule or not):

```
machine your.artifactory.host
        password YOUR_TOKEN
```

How this works is for given host it takes string of the corresponding `auth_patterns` value, replaces `<login>` and `<password>` (if used) with those obtained for given host from `netrc` and passes that as value for `Authorization` header. I.e. in the above example:

```
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_TOKEN
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using bazel 0.22. Looks like authentication is not in bazel 0.22

Comment: Yes. It was shortly introduced in 0.29 and pulled 0.29.1. It then came back to stay in version 1.1. For older versions, we used to use a custom repository rule to do the fetching with authentication. Alternatively, you can run a trivial authenticating proxy on localhost for the purpose against which bazel can make the requests and which relays the requests to remote serve using required authentication.