# How can I arrange for Bazel dependencies to be cached on a server local to my organization, to mitigate supply-chain risks?

Tags: bazel

I work in a large organisation, and we are considering using Bazel as a build tool for our large repo.

Bazel has a number of dependencies (such as specific build rules) that in turn have their own dependencies, and those dependencies are hosted on github.

Our company would like to avoid risks, such as github being down and us having to use our CI, so some say that we should host all those dependencies internally. The problem is that all those deps urls are hardcoded into the `rules_<something>` code and it's not quite clear how to do it with reasonable effort.

The question is, does it really make sense? Doesn't it go against the approach that the developers of Bazel chose? Or is there a good way to create those local caches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a good way: `--experimental_downloader_config`.

See also: https://bazel.build/reference/command-line-reference#flag--experimental_downloader_config

Essentially you provide a config that disallows downloads from everywhere except your company internal cache and rewrites all URLs to use that internal cache.

As for how to setup the cache: any caching proxy should do. Artifactory or Nexus come to mind.

Comment: And as a blog post: https://blog.aspect.dev/configuring-bazels-downloader

Comment: Thank you, this works great, but is there a way to also specify global `auth_patterns`? The problem is that our internal storages require authentication, and, again, all those `http_archives` are hardcoded in third-party repos and we don't want to have to edit them

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61146845/20546409 hints at a global `~/.netrc` file. Otherwise you can look at https://bazel.build/reference/command-line-reference#flag--credential_helper.

Comment: This works only if we add `auth_patterns` to the corresponding `http_archive`s. This works for the our own dependencies we download directly from our gitlab, but it didn't seem to work for the rewritten urls

Comment: I'm trying to make credentials helper work, but Bazel fails with exit code 37 (internal Bazel error). I've written a bash file `echo "{\"headers\": {\"Authorization\": [\"Bearer not-telling-ya\"]}}"`, but the file doesn't even start executing (checked by adding a sleep). (on bazel 6.3.2, 6.3.1, 6.3.0)